# How to use "would" and "used to"

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is the difference in below sentences between "would" and "used to"?

> 1) When he was free, he **would** go to the movies.
>
> 2) When he was free, he **used to** go to the movies.

And

> 3) When I was in 10th Std you **would** teach me English.
>
> 4) When I was in 10th Std you **used to** teach me English.

Comment: Format the question please. It's not understandable.

Comment: It's spelled "used to". An answer to that question was given on [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/60812/12918).

Comment: @ user4084: Your examples 1 & 2 are pretty much identical (both *would* and *used to* are being used to mean *were in the habit of*). But 4 is a slightly "stretched" usage where *you **used to** do something* has more the sense of *you did it [continuously/repeatedly] over an extended period of time*. Which is somewhat different to 3 - a rather unlikely construction where the most credible interpretation is more like *you would [sometimes] teach me*.